# How do you get the area under a curve that is not represented by a function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I looked for answers on how to do this on this on this site and couldn't find anything answering this question. Is this what a line integral is used for or is that only to find area under a function f(x,y) along a curve C (on xy-plane for example)?

Comment: Can you show us your curve?

Comment: I don't have a specific curve I need the area under, I just want to know how to get the area under any curve that isn't represented by a function (for example: an "S"-like figure in the xy-plane).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to know the function to get the area under it. If you don't have the function then you should approximate it in MATLAB by collecting some sample data from the graph. Besides, Line integral is in the first place used to determine the curve length not the area under it. But while doing line integral you also need the function or have to parametrize the curve.

Answer (score 0):

If your data
is a set of
$(x_i, y_i)$
points with
$x_i < x_{i+1}$,
a simple estimate is

$\dfrac12\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)(y_i+y_{i+1})
$.

If the $x_i$
are equally spaced.
Simpson's rule is more accurate.

It depends what info you have
about the $x_i$.